# Querying With MongoDate vs UTCDateTime

Tags: php, mongodb, datetime

After upgrading to the new Mongo Driver for PHP, I am facing the problem of sorting and querying dates.

The old driver used: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php which stored dates in a MongoDate object in seconds.

The new driver: http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php stores the date in a different format and stores it in milliseconds.

The has rendered querying with $gte or $lte useless. Example:

```
$collection -> find(array('start_date' => array('$gte' => new MongoDate())));

$collection -> find(array('start_date' => array('$gte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime())));
```

These two do not return the same result. With all the old data, how can I safely still query with both MongoDate and UTCDateTime?

Comment: Could you [enable profiler](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.setProfilingLevel/) and show what queries both drivers generate?

Comment: According to the documentation, unlike `MongoDate`, `UTCDateTime` must be manually passed the timestamp in milliseconds, like `new UTCDateTime(round(microtime(true) * 1000));`. This renders your code invalid and unable to be reproduced in order to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the time in milliseconds instead of seconds, and everything will keep working like before:

```
$time = time();
$cursor = $collection->find(['start_date' => ['$gte' => new MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime($time * 1000)]]);
```